# Use more than one MongoDb collection in a single app

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have an app which uses `MongoDb` and I am connecting to `MongoDb` by calling `MongooseModule.forRoot` in `replies.module.ts`, now I have another module called `replies.module.ts` and I want to connect to another collection but in the same database, should I use the same method in the new module and just change the collection name? does it won't create a duplicate connection to mongo? what is the best practice for that?

**Reviews module: `reviews.module.ts`**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb+srv://user:password@url/reviews?retryWrites=true&w=majority',),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Review', schema: ReviewSchema}
    ])],
    controllers: [ReviewsController],
    providers: [ReviewsService]
})
```

**Replies module: `replies.module.ts`**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb+srv://user:password@url/replies?retryWrites=true&w=majority',),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Replies', schema: RepliesSchema}
    ])],
    controllers: [RepliesController],
    providers: [RepliesService]
})
```

Comment: from both files move `forRoot(''mongodb+srv://user:password@YOUR_DB_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority'')` in the `app.module.ts` file. and keep `forFeature`

Comment: Yes, but to move it where? to `app.module.ts`? And if so, how to call a specific collection from each module?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want by naming your connections:

**app.module.ts:**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb+srv://user:password@url/reviews?retryWrites=true&w=majority',  { connectionName: 'ReviewsDB' }),
        MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb+srv://user:password@url/replies?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { connectionName: 'RepliesDB' })
]})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

Then you can use your models, for examples in dedicatied modules:

**review.module.ts :**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Review.name, schema: ReviewSchema }], 'ReviewsDB')
    ],
    providers: [ReviewService],
    exports: [ReviewService],
})

export class ReviewModule {}
```

And the for replies:

**reply.module.ts :**

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Reply.name, schema: ReplySchema }], 'RepliesDB')
    ],
    providers: [ReplyService],
    exports: [ReplyService],
})

export class ReplyModule {}
```

Do not forget to set the `connection name` of the wanted database in your `forFeature` declaration